# Truncate a SQLite table if it exists?

Tags: sqlite

To truncate a table in SQLite I need to use this syntax:

```
DELETE FROM someTable
```

But how do I truncate the table only if it exists?

Unfortunately this throws an error:

```
DELETE FROM someTable IF EXISTS
```

This doesn't work either:

```
DELETE IF EXISTS FROM someTable
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

IMHO, it is more efficient to drop the table and re-create it. And yes, you can use "IF EXISTS" in this case.

Comment: +1 Right. There is no "If EXISTS" currently for delete in SQLite, so your approach works well.

Comment: `DELETE FROM` will cause SQLite to visit individual rows unless those rows have triggers, so it's generally reasonably efficient.

Comment: @Brian Since 3.6.5, SQLite has introduced a "truncate" optimization for avoiding the visit of individual rows. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14402146/363573

Comment: not if you have foreign keys or triggers which would prevent you from dropping the table

Comment: In case you are not dropping the table, don't forget to reset `autoincrement` by clearing relevant row on `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table

Comment: is still more efficente to drop the table in the latest version of SQLite? Even with the truncate optimization?

Comment: @jalopezsuarez: just dropping and recreating table instead of querying metadata for table existence and conditionally deleting its contents and resetting its sequence seems more efficient to me (even for simple table without triggers and fkeys).

Comment: As of 2023-12-22, table SQLITE_SEQUENCE does not appear to exist because DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = "name of table"; FAILS with the error message "Result: no such table: SQLITE_SEQUENCE"

Answer (score 95):

It is the two step process:

1. Delete all data from that table using:

   ```
   Delete from TableName
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
   DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='TableName';
   ```

Comment: I assume the 2nd one resets the auto-inc counter?

Comment: @DanMan Yes you are correct second statement will reset the index.

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation of SQLITE_SEQUENCE

Comment: If I do not execute second command to reset `autoincrement`, will the autoinc counter continue where it stopped on the deleted table for following tables? Example: last `autoincrement` in old table is `5`, I create a new table and it starts counting with `6`?

Answer (score 50):

Just do `delete`. This is from the SQLite documentation:

> [The Truncate Optimization](http://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)
>
> "When the WHERE is omitted from a DELETE statement and the table being deleted has no triggers, SQLite uses an optimization to erase the entire table content without having to visit each row of the table individually. This "truncate" optimization makes the delete run much faster. Prior to SQLite version 3.6.5, the truncate optimization also meant that the sqlite3_changes() and sqlite3_total_changes() interfaces and the count_changes pragma will not actually return the number of deleted rows. That problem has been fixed as of version 3.6.5."

Comment: And don't forget to reset `autoincrement` by clearing relevant row on `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table

Answer (score 8):

I got it to work with:

```
SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

Comment: But primary key column is set into auto increment.then it's will increment.

Answer (score 8):

After deleting I'm also using `VACUUM` command. So for full `TRUNCATE` equivalent I use this code:

```
DELETE FROM <table>;
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = '<table>';
VACUUM;
```

Deleting isn't working for me for reset Auto Increment

```
DELETE FROM "sqlite_sequence" WHERE "name"='<table>';
```

To read more about VACUUM you can go here: https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2015/01/06/sqlite-vacuum-and-auto_vacuum/

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master where name = '<TABLE_NAME_HERE>'
```

If the table name does not exist then there would not be any records returned!

You can as well use

```
SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master where name = '<TABLE_NAME_HERE>'
```

> if the count is 1, means table exists, otherwise, it would return 0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not have a "TRUNCATE TABLE" command in SQLite, but you can use SQLite's `DELETE` command to delete the complete data from an existing table, though it is recommended to use the `DROP TABLE` command to drop the complete table and re-create it once again.

Answer (score 0):

"sqllite" dosn't have "TRUNCATE " order like than mysql, then we have to get other way...
this function (reset_table) frist delete all data in table and then reset AUTOINCREMENT key in table....
now you can use this function every where you want...

example :

```
private SQLiteDatabase mydb;
private final String dbPath = "data/data/your_project_name/databases/";
private final String dbName = "your_db_name";


public void reset_table(String table_name){
    open_db();

    mydb.execSQL("Delete from "+table_name);
    mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='"+table_name+"';");

    close_db();
}

public void open_db(){

    mydb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath + dbName + ".db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public void close_db(){

    mydb.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is Simple, just follow 2 steps.
Step #1. Fire query "Delete from tableName", It will delete all records from table.

Step #2. There is table named "sqlite_sequence" in Sqlite Database, just browse it and you can set sequence table wise to "0" so it will start from auto id "1".**
See the screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**there is no truncate command in sqlite.**

**but can be achieved by:**

1. delete all records;
   `Delete from 'Table1';`

then

2. set auto-increment to 0;
   `UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'Table1';`