# delete all query or drop query

Tags: android, sqlite

which was more preferable as performance wise and without error cause to delete all the row from table in sqlite in android.

DELETE QUERY OR DROP TABLE AND RE-GENERATE THE TABLE

I have found this from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280041/sqlite-truncate-a-table-if-exists/4280131#4280131)

```
it is more efficient to drop table and re-create it; and yes, You can use "IF EXISTS" in this case

DELETE FROM will cause SQLite to visit individual rows unless those rows have triggers, so it's generally reasonably efficient.


edited after 1 answer post

As the Droping the table using drop table query then internally delete query was used? As in one answer post
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the sqlite query I found the answer. In sqlite they have used the Truncation Optimization so when the "where" clause was omitted they drop the table and re-create the table this is much faster than delete all rows.

here is the links for that

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_truncate_optimization

Comment: Yes.
It says:
A default build of SQLite, if a DELETE statement has no WHERE clause and operates on a table with no triggers, an optimization occurs that causes the DELETE to occur by dropping and recreating the table. Dropping and recreating a table is usually much faster than deleting the table content row by row. This is the "truncate optimization".

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge **DELETE QUERY** is the better option.why because the Drop table internally uses the delete query. If you use the Drop query ,you have to regenerate the table.This is one more extra process.