# What is the best way in Android to delete all rows from a table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a WCF witch provides some JSON data and then I save it into the local database. Works fine
I have a Activity witch fills the data from a local database to a listview witch works fine.

```
public void fillData() {

    // Fields from the database (projection)
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
    String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from,
            to, 0);

    lw.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What I can't figure out is what would be the best way to delete all rows prior to a sync action from a WCF.

I could do this by getting all Id's from the database then find the row URI and then use:

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)
```

I just think that there has to be a better way I saw many examples on the net that uses the DbHelper class but I can't figure out how to access the dbHelper class from the Activity or over the ContentProvider

Hope that makes any sense

Comment: if you have own ContentProvider then `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)` is ok ... but ... uri should not point to specific "item" but rather to whole "dir" (`content://com.authority/tablename/111` <= item uri, `content://com.authority/tablename` <= dir uri)

Comment: you dont need to find all the id's of the database if you do it that way. All you have to do is give it the uri of the database and not a specific item

Comment: sorry that was jsut me being newbish :( @Selvin . Your answer done it. Ty. Make a reply so I can except it. the proper code is: ' getContentResolver().delete(TodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null); '

Comment: then answer to your question by yourself :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete all query or drop query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401609/delete-all-query-or-drop-query)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `DatabaseHelper` you can do like this:

```
 dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
 database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

public void clearTable()   {
    database.delete(TABLE, null,null);
}
```

Comment: does this delete the entire table though? i still need table just want to clear rows out

Comment: @Tintinabulator Zea this will only delete all rows from the given table. More info:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: this is not optimal because it doesn't notify for data change. you should override your delete method in content provider

Comment: @hadi The question is about deleting rows, not notyfing content provider. Besides OP uses SimpleCursorAdapter to fetch rows so I don't see any reason to notify content provider.

Comment: @soulreaver notifying content provider is a good practice when that row is being showed in UI. if you r not using your database in a view so never mind :)

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
<your-SQLite-instance>.execSQL("DELETE FROM <table_name>");
```

That will drop all the rows from `<table_name>`

Comment: read documentation: execSQL()
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/ **DELETE**.

Comment: @Selvin you should read it too, that's for `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` NOT for `execSQL(String sql)`. The code I posted is used in production, and works...

Comment: ok so: `It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows).` DELETE returns number of affected `The code I posted is used in production, and works` but you should be encouraged to use insert/update/delete instead (as is stated in `execSQL(String sql)` doc)

Comment: and from android source: `public void execSQL(String sql) throws SQLException {executeSql(sql, null);}` and 
`public void execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs) throws SQLException { /*null check*/executeSql(sql, bindArgs);}` ... they are the same function ...

Comment: And yet, my code still works to perform the exact function the poster requested. It's simply executing a sql statement, Jester needed sql to be performed, those line up well.

Comment: `<your-SQLite-instance>.delete("<table_name>", null,null);` should do the trick too, without SQL carving ... why this is better? first: you can get numbers of row affected,  second: we always use something like  `interface TableName { public static final String Name= "Name"; public static final String Col1 = "Col1";}` then we use it ... so what looks better `db.delete(TableName.Name, null,null);` or `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TableName.Name);`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code to delete all rows in a table :

```
database.delete(tablename, null,null);
```

Just replace `database` for your db name and `tablename` for the table you want to delete the rows

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to delete all the rows on a table:

```
drop table if exists "tablename"
```

And then recreate the table with the appropriate columns. I personally find it a lot easier to do it this way.

Comment: This is not a great idea, since you have to keep different versions of your create table query if you plan on upgrading your DB.

Comment: I usually took a patch approach to that, you'd keep the old creation and apply any necessary update statements to the table. Then you can apply all the statements on creation (make them safely fail if it's non-applicable) and keep them up-to-date per launch. This doesn't work as well on a multi-instance setup though (where you would want the central db to be set up properly beforehand)

Comment: This will not be a good idea to clear table. However you can find easy solution by SQL own delete query.