# What's the best way to delete all data from a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table with 6 million rows.

Doing a DELETE FROM TABLE is quite slow;

Dropping the table and then re-creating it seems quicker.

I'm using this for a database import.

Would dropping the table be a better approach or is there a way to delete all data quickly?

Comment: have you tried doing a `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a `TRUNCATE`, but its supposed to make a truncate optimization when there is a `DELETE` without a `WHERE`

Comment: @Lamak i know in MySQL DELETE without a WHERE is equivalent to TRUNCATE

Comment: @Lamak It doesnt seem very optimized to me :)

Comment: @Jon - that's th odd part, since it should automaticly drop and recreate your table if there are no triggers. http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_truncate_optimization

Comment: Weird. I'm using C# to do it so unless there is some bottleneck in System.Data.SQLite http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big difference is that `DELETE FROM TABLE` is DML and `DROP TABLE` is DDL. This is very important when it comes to db transactions. The result at the end may be the same, but these operations are very different.

If it's just performance you've to be aware of then it may be ok to drop and recreate the table. If you need transactions in your imports then you've to be aware that DDL is not covered and cannot be rollbacked for example.

Comment: At the moment the first thing I do is drop it and then recreated it and then create a transaction and import the data.

Comment: ..and when your transaction have to be rollbacked? Is it ok that the table is empty? Or must it contain the data before failed import?

Comment: Then you might be fine with the faster solution with dropping and recreating the table as long as there are no other concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the DROP TABLE would be a non-logged transaction. DELETE FROM would require a transient journal to log the records until the DELETE statement has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

TRUNCATE TABLE  is a lot faster.

The following except from an Oracle website explains why:

'Deletes' perform normal DML. That is, they take locks on rows, they generate redo (lots of it), and they require segments in the UNDO tablespace. Deletes clear records out of blocks carefully. If a mistake is made a rollback can be issued to restore the records prior to a commit. A delete does not relinquish segment space thus a table in which all records have been deleted retains all of its original blocks.

Truncates are DDL and, in a sense, cheat. A truncate moves the High Water Mark of the table back to zero. No row-level locks are taken, no redo or rollback is generated. All extents bar the initial are de-allocated from the table (if you have MINEXTENTS set to anything other than 1, then that number of extents is retained rather than just the initial). By re-positioning the high water mark, they prevent reading of any table data, so they have the same effect as a delete, but without all the overhead. Just one slight problem: a truncate is a DDL command, so you can't roll it back if you decide you made a mistake. (It's also true that you can't selectively truncate -no "WHERE" clause is permitted, unlike with deletes, of course).

By resetting the High Water Mark, the truncate prevents reading of any table's data, so they it has the same effect as a delete, but without the overhead. There is, however, one aspect of a Truncate that must be kept in mind. Because a Truncate is DDL it issues a COMMIT before it acts and another COMMIT afterward so no rollback of the transaction is possible.

Note that by default, TRUNCATE drops storage even if DROP STORAGE is not specified.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that ur using sqlite. I think this post answers ur question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280041/sqlite-truncate-a-table-if-exists

Comment: That is a very precise answer to a question the user did not ask.  The user is working with SQLite, a very different animal from Oracle.

Comment: @Larry Lustig - Yes I didn't realise that TRUNCATE wasn't available. My bad. That said, the gist of why TRUNCATE is faster is relevant to DBs other than Oracle which do implement TRUNCATE, e.g. SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQLite implements `TRUNCATE` but if it does it likely will be more performant than `DELETE`