# Clear all items from a table in Sqlite3 IPHONE? supported? DROP TABLE? DELETE FROM TABLA_1?

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to delete all data from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086630/whats-the-best-way-to-delete-all-data-from-a-table)

Clear all items from a table in Sqlite3 IPHONE? supported? DROP TABLE? DELETE FROM TABLA_1?

```
   - (void) DeleteDataSqlite3 {
    NSLog(@"Borra data");
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement; 
    NSString *querySQL = @"DELETE FROM EVENTOS";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    //Open d
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &eventosDB) == SQLITE_OK){
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(eventosDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"oK");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Error !query");
        }
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Open error");
    }
   sqlite3_close(eventosDB); 
   }
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please don't put tag information in the title - that's what tags are for. And don't use things like "dude" - keep your questions concise and readable, without cluttering with noise, if you want to be able to get help. :) You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the parts about how to ask a better question in order to get an answer more quickly. Thanks. :)

Comment: Made a mistake, I can edit the title?

Comment: [The `public dude` abides...](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/modHmm.aspx)

Comment: @Jack Maney, Not laughed so much at some code in a long time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern databases including SQLite support rapid mass deletes. In practice there is not much to gain from dropping the table instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the table then recreate it, however when I want to clear out a database, I just delete the SQLite file and let iOS copy a new one from the package.