# How to completely clean SQLite3 database and import fresh data?

Tags: ruby, database, import, sqlite

I have a dump data from our production SQLite3 database. On the localhost there's a local SQLite3 database for the respective project. I need to import the dump of the database from production to the local database.

How do I do that? Do I need to remove the local SQLite3 database, or, if I run the import of the SQLite3 database from production, will the production data overwrite the records in the local database?

It's a database for a Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite databases are just flat files. You can just download the the database file from your server. You find it here: `#{Rails.root}/db/production.sqlite3`. Than replace your local development database file at `#{Rails.root}/db/development.sqlite3` with the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting in the habit of either truncating the table, or dropping it and recreating it, prior to loading the data. If/when you move from SQLite to a DBM like MySQL or PostgreSQL, you'll find that same technique will work well.

See "[Truncate a SQLite table if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4280041/128421)" for more information.